# ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-compiler

In a process of migration from webpack2 to **webpack4** and from Angular4 to **Angular5** I'm getting strange error for webpack compilation (./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli):

> ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core

Debugging webpack (`node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli`) got an error stack trace:

```
Error: Could not resolve module @angular/core
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolByModule (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29766:30)
    at StaticReflector.findDeclaration (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31635:63)
    at StaticReflector.initializeConversionMap (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31953:36)
    at new StaticReflector (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31571:14)
    at Object.createAotCompiler (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:32957:44)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._createCompiler (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:404:37)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.get [as hostAdapter] (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:327:22)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._createProgramWithBasicStubs (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:435:73)
    at .../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:143:28
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
```

But unfortunately it still does not give a hint.

Here is [package.json dependancies](https://pastebin.com/X1LcgpYV).

Reported this [issue on angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23160) repo.

Comment: Try removing the node_modules directory and installing the node modules again.

Comment: already tried :(  also probably should add that problem is reproducible on another machine

Answer (score 0):

I fact installing module `@angular-devkit/core` solved the problem

Comment: is not the samething i have posted below?

Comment: try to find but cannot see "angular-devkit" in your messages

Comment: In my case, I stored it in C:\users\earlg\documents\projects#dev\ng-test-app.
it seems to omit the path from #. Renaming my folder to projects-dev solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this today using Angular 10. This message continued even after a clean install

```
npm ci
ng build
ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core
```

We were working on a library install at the time, updating the library and installing new versions each new update. The root cause of this issue was that an NPM Uninstall of that library somehow didn't tell webpack the information. (or perhaps we just removed the lib entry in package.json). Thus the build failure wasn't really @angular/core it was that web pack could not find our library to install.

The fix: We re-installed our library again.

```
npm install libName // which put a new entry into package.json
```

It's a known fact that webpack error messages are the worst, they tell us nothing as to who, where or why... How do we know this was a web-pack compile time error message?

```
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
```